# Add HTML to a table only if it has more than X amount of "tds" with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add an HTML block to a table(s) if more than 3 td elements are found, and not do anything if the table(s) have less than 3 td elements. I have looped through the tables, and have been able to check how many tds are in each table.

I have tried using .filter(); and $.each() but couldn't crack it.

So: >> How do I only add the HTML to the Tables that passed the if > 3 statement ?

I am still learning JavaScript and jQuery so please bear with me.

here is the code so far:

```
var tbls = $("body").find("table.responsive").length;   
var data = Array();

for(var index = 0; index < tbls; index++){ 
    $("table.responsive").each(function(i, v){
        data[i] = Array();
        $(this).find("td").each(function(ii, vv){
            data[i][ii] = $(this).text();
    }); 
  })
}

data.forEach(function(item) { 
    if(item.length > 3) {

      //here I want to add the HTML, but it is applied to all tables
      $("table.responsive").before("<div style='position:relative;'><span class='MobiScroll'></span></div>");
    return false;          
     } 
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/design4lifeblog/gSPXu/15/

Comment: I guess I need to Learn to "this" more. Thanks everybody for the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to start traversing from body element and making an array for this, you can count the TDs in an each function.

```
$("table.responsive").​each(function(){
    if ( $('td', this).length > 3) {
       $(this).before("<div style='position:relative;'><span class='MobiScroll'></span></div>");
    }
})​
```

Comment: _All human actions have one or more of these seven causes: chance, nature, compulsions, habit, reason, passion, desire._ 
"Aristotle"

Comment: Wow thanks for the swift reply, works great. I feared it would be this simple!

Comment: @ClydeLobo The reason remains unknown.

Comment: I'm impressed, it's not often you see Aristotelian references within a discussion of JavaScript or html... =)

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes :), nowadays we read _docs_ more than _Aristotle_. I've missed those days that I was a philosophy bookworm.

Comment: I must confess that I never read much of Aristotle's work, but I have always enjoyed reading Foucault and Baudrillard (of almost no use to JavaScript, for the most part, but still fascinating; critical theory and philosophy are, often, amazing). =)

Comment: @DavidThomas Great, I like Nieztche's work and Existentialism. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $("table.responsive").each(function(){
    if ( $(this).find('td').length > 3) {
       $(this).before("<div style='position:relative;'><span class='MobiScroll'></span></div>");
        //alert($(this))
    }
})});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gSPXu/20/)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, this seems great too:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table.responsive").each(function(){
  if($(this).find('td').size() > 3)
    $(this).before("<div style='position:relative;'><span class='MobiScroll'></span></div>");
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pKWXZ/1/